# NetSuite - PowerBI - Error while loading data to transform

Tags: powerbi, odbc, analytics, netsuite

I'm trying to transform data in PowerBI from the NetSuite table "TRANSACTION_LINES" (one of the main tables of NetSuite ERP) using the ODBC connector provided by SuiteAnalytics Connect. After clicking the "Transform Data" button, the Power Query Editor is opened and after a (good) while the message is displayed:
[image: PowerBI Error NetSuite ODBC]

"Preview.Error: The type of the current preview value is too complex to display.
Details:"

There is no details at all.

Any guess about what is happening here? Is this a limitation from PowerBI?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on similar reports before using ODBC connection. The table mentioned "TRANSACTION_LINES" is really big and complex one. You need to write a query in order to narrow down the results to the exact report that you want to build. If you are also pulling data from "TRANSACTION" table along with "TRANSACTION_LINES" then you need to have joins.

Also, in your question, you have not mentioned the "Transaction type" on which you want to build this report.Please also update the query that you have built.

Here is a sample below for your reference to just pull data from 1 line so that you would get to know if the query works. Once you are sure, then you can build it for a larger data set. The value XXXX would be internal id of any transaction line

```
SELECT
transaction_lines.transaction_id,
transaction_lines.transaction_line_id,
items.type_name,
items.name,
items.purchasedescription
FROM
transaction_lines
WHERE
transaction_lines.transaction_id = XXXX
```